# cannot access postgres db running docker container from local machine

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have been spending 3-4 hours on this and still have not found a solution.

I can successfully run the docker container and use psql from the container bash, however, when I try to call the db from my local machine I continue to get this error message:

`error role "postgres" does not exist`

I have already tried editing "listen_addresses" in the postgresql.conf file from the container bash

My setup:
I am using a macbook - Monterey 12.4

my docker compose file:
version: '3.4'

```
services:
 postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres_db
      - POSTGRES_USER=testUser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=testPW
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/db
```

**but this issue occurs if I do it through the standard CLI command as well, i.e:**

```
docker run -d -p 5432:5432 --name my-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword postgres
```

I tried to follow this tutorial but it didnt work:
[https://betterprogramming.pub/connect-from-local-machine-to-postgresql-docker-container-f785f00461a7][1]

when I try this command:
`psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -W`

it doesnt work:
`psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`

Also for reference, the user "postgres" does exist in postgres - as a superuser

Comment: The environment variables with username etc. are only used if a database doesn't exist. If a database exists, the existing users etc. in the database are used. Try running without a volume to make sure that a fresh database is created.

Comment: "Also for reference, the user "postgres" does exist in postgres - as a superuser"  Usually it does, but you just told it not to do that, to use "testUser" instead.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all for your help on this.

It turns out the issue was that I was running postgres on my local machine as well.

so once I turn that off I was able to connect.

I appreciate your time!

Comment: This is the answer!

Answer (score -1):

Replace `POSTGRES_USER=testUser` with `POSTGRES_USER=postgres` in the compose configuration. Also use the password defined in `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`. Delete the old container and create a new one.